# maven-surefire-plugin missing in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jakarta-ee

when I'm building a maven project I got this error .....

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.790s
[INFO] Finished at: Sun May 11 09:36:22 IST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/111M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test    (default-test) on project javaeeapp: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test failed: Unable to load the mojo 'test' in the plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.10'. A required class is missing: org/apache/maven/plugin/surefire/SurefireReportParameters
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.10
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/C:/Users/NOughT/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/2.10/maven-surefire-plugin-2.10.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/C:/Users/NOughT/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-booter/2.10/surefire-booter-2.10.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/C:/Users/NOughT/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/surefire/maven-surefire-common/2.10/maven-surefire-common-2.10.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/C:/Users/NOughT/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/2.1/plexus-utils-2.1.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------: org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefireReportParameters
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException
```

how I add maven surefire plugin to eclipse??

Comment: I am new for this.can you help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add `Maven Surefire Plugin` in `pom.xml`.
Refer sample `pom.xml` here:

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <!-- To define the plugin version in your parent POM -->
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.17</version>
        </plugin>
        ...
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <!-- To use the plugin goals in your POM or parent POM -->
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.17</version>
      </plugin>
      ...
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

Comment: worth to note that either of both entries <pluginmanagement><plugins><plugin>... or <plugins><plugin>.. is to be used not both in parallel. dont forget the version, will lead into maven warning else

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same error got resolved by going to add dependency 
and add the following dependency
1.maven surfire plugin
2.maven surfire common
3.surfire api
4.surfire booter

By downloading all this in my pom.xml My issue got resolved